# ASP.net pages rewriting to .html issue

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am rewriting .aspx pages to .html in web.config file.My registration.aspx page is rewriting to localhost/registration.html.
I found some issues,

> 1. if i type localhost/registration.htmltesting instead of localhost/registration.html
> 2. if i type localhost/registration.html?testing instead of localhost/registration.html
> 3. if i type localhost/registration.html/testing instead of localhost/registration.html

above all cases the page should redirects to 404 error page. but its redirecting to `localhost/registration.html`.

Is there any solution for this ??

Comment: fix redirection in web.config?

Comment: need to fix it in web.config. Any solutions ?